# Error Code: 1146. Table 'college_small.result' doesn't exist while using sql temporary tables

Tags: mysql

My sql statement is as follows：

```
SELECT course_id FROM (
(SELECT COUNT(course_id) AS count FROM takes GROUP BY course_id) AS result) 
WHERE count IN (SELECT MAX(count) FROM result)
```

How can I use temporary tables twice?For example,the table "result" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to obtain the `course_id` which has the maximum number of takes, then you can order the subquery by the count and limit the result set to one record.

```
SELECT course_id, COUNT(course_id) AS count
FROM takes
GROUP BY course_id
ORDER BY COUNT(course_id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you also want to obtain all course id values, in the event that there be a tie for the maximum number of takes, then you can try the following slightly more complicated query:

```
SELECT result.course_id
FROM
(
    SELECT course_id, COUNT(course_id) AS count
    FROM takes
    GROUP BY course_id
) AS result
WHERE result.count = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM takes
    GROUP BY course_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: It really works.It can help me solve the question.But I still want to ask about using temporary tables twice.Maybe is it not usual in practice

Comment: One common way of reusing a temporary table is a construct called a _common table expression_ (CTE).  SQL Server, Oracle, and Postgres all support this feature, but alas MySQL does not support it.  You might be able to reuse a temporary table in MySQL using views or dynamic SQL though.